# Laravel Route not passing object

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I am working on a Laravel application and I have a blade file with a link to open a user patient profile, when clicked it loads the page to show the patient, however that page is not getting passed the user object, and i can't figure out why

I have tried to write my route for the page like i have for other pages and the route is defined, but still not passing

Route

```
Route::get('/viewPatient/{patient}', 'PatientController@show')->name('patients.viewPatient');
```

link

```
<td><a href="{{route('patients.viewPatient', $user)}}">{{$user->firstname}}</a></td>
```

controller function, if i die and dump it litteraly just returns an empty user object.

```
public function show(User $user)
    {
        dd($user);
        return view('patients.show', compact('user'));
    }
```

the expected result is the show method needs to recieve the user object, it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your variable the same name as when it is passed into the route, like so:

`public function show(User $patient)`

Comment: ok, i changed patient in the route to user and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

//change it like this

```
<td><a href="{{route('patients.viewPatient', $user->id)}}">{{$user->firstname}}</a></td>
```

//in your controller

```
public function show($id) //$id you can write $patientId
{
    $user = User::where('id',$id)->first();
    return view('patients.show', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: This works, but is there any way to pass it the whole user object to reduce database operations?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<a href="{{route('patients.viewPatient', ['patient'=>$user->id])}}">{{$user->firstname}}</a>
```